# Wrong scatter label color in pyplot legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I am making this bar plot:
[image]

... using this code segment:

```
my_cmap = plt.get_cmap('copper')

plt.figure()
plt.set_cmap(my_cmap)
plt.pcolormesh(xx, yy, Z)

labels = ['Negative', 'Negative (doubtful)', 'Positive (doubtful)', 'Positive' ]
for i in [0, 1, 2, 3] :
    plt.scatter(clustered_training_data[y==i, 0], clustered_training_data[y==i, 1], c=my_cmap(i / 3.0), label=labels[i], s=50, marker='o', edgecolor='white', alpha=0.7)

plt.scatter(lda_trans_eval[q == -1, 0], lda_trans_eval[q == -1, 1], c='green', label='Your patient', s=80, marker='h', edgecolor='white')

plt.legend(prop={'size':8})
```

Only one (second) color is always blue, regardless of chosen color map. Corresponding data points are correctly colored in the plot and I can't see the reason why pyplot colors the second label differently.

Comment: I agree, this looks odd. Could you provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example (with data)? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. And by the way, why would you call that a *bar plot*?

Comment: That's a typo, it's clearly scatter plot. I will genera MVE and update the question.

Comment: what was your solution? I have the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce it with dummy data. Does this have the problem when you run it?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
my_cmap = plt.get_cmap('copper')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
plt.set_cmap(my_cmap)

X = np.linspace(-1,5,100)
Y = np.linspace(-1,5,100)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(X,Y)
Z = (X**2 + Y**2)
Z = Z.astype(int)
Z += (X**2 + Y**2) < .5

ax = plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z)
for i in [0,1,2,3]:
    plt.scatter([i],[i],c=my_cmap(i / 3.0),label='i=%s'%str(i),
    edgecolor='white', alpha=0.7)

plt.scatter([],[],c=my_cmap(1/3.0), label='empty data')
plt.scatter([3],[1],c='green',label='Force color')
plt.legend(loc=2, prop={'size':8})
from os.path import realpath, basename
s = basename(realpath(__file__))
fig.savefig(s.split('.')[0])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This works on my machine normally, it looks the same as on our picture. :-/

Comment: Could you possibly be plotting the Negative (doubtful) case twice?

Comment: (I'm not sure what your comment meant. Does this example, with dummy data, have blue dots for the i=1 legend?)

Comment: The comment should say "it looks the same as on your picture", sorry. Your example gives no error when I run it (legend shows normal colors) and my example still fails.

Comment: Huh. Well, I guess I'd start from the no-error case, and add in your particular data, and see where it switches...

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me. I fixed it by using `color` instead of `c`.

```
plt.scatter(clustered_training_data[y==i, 0], clustered_training_data[y==i, 1], color=my_cmap(i / 3.0), label=labels[i], s=50, marker='o', edgecolor='white', alpha=0.7)
```